# How to translate from French: "on fait une photo ?"

Tags: translation

I'm French and I'd like to translate this in English.

> On fait une photo ?

or

> On se prend en photo ?

**Context:** My friend and I are in front of a nice monument/place and I want to propose them to take a picture of ourself.

Comment: It's often difficult for us to do translations from your language to English because it requires we be able to understand your language... they're also [off-topic](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). So, it's best for you to not bother with the phrase in French and simply propose a phrase and ask if it's correct.

Comment: Somebody else can't take a picture of "ourself".  Only **we** can take a picture of ourselves.  Someone else would be taking a picture of **us**.  "Would you please take a picture of us?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to phrase this and it's up to you how you wish to say it. Here are a few options for you:

> (Do you) Want to take a photo (together) (in front of this building)?

The simplest question. It can be made more specific by adding the parts in parenthesis. Adding the leading "do you" is optional. Without "do you", the phrase is quite informal but natural to a native speaker.

> Let's take a picture together (in front of this monument).

The statement form is also useful but your friend can still decline.

Or, if you're younger* and want to use one of the most recent additions to the English language, you can say

> Let's take a [selfie](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/selfie) (in front of this building)!
>
> "A photograph that one has taken of oneself, typically one taken with a smartphone or webcam and shared via social media"

This is very informal and it's important to know that the implication is that you will be holding the camera yourself rather than finding someone to hold it for you.

---

* Age usage for "selfie" is debatable. I'm not a personal fan of the word and it certainly seems more popular amongst the under 30s... but older people do use it, including celebrities:

[image: Ellen DeGeneres Selfie]